# How to get the difference between numbers using dc?

Tags: dc

Input:

```
> printf 1\n\2\n3\n
1
2
3
```

Desired output:

```
0
1
1
```

Typing `printf 1\n\2\n3\n | dc -e '-p'` the output is:

```
dc: stack empty
dc: stack empty
```

Comment: 0=1-undefined or something like that... the first 1 is 2-1, the seccond 3-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pipe the entire set of commands directly to `dc`.

```
printf "1 2 3 - - p" | dc
```

If you'd like to subtract an arbitrary stack you can use a macro.

```
printf "%s [-z1<r]srz1<rp" "<insert numbers here>" | dc
```

So for example

```
printf "%s [-z1<r]srz1<rp" "100 5 2 1" | dc
96
```

The macro does the following:

- `[` Start macro
- `-` Subtract top two numbers and push back to stack
- `z1<r` Push stack size to stack and 1, then compare LESSTHAN, if true run `r` macro
- `]sr` End of macro, store in register r
- `z1<r` Check if stack contains elements by testing `1 < Stack Size`
- `p` Print result.
- `

Comment: This doesn't look like the actual desired output at all.  It only prints one number.